# Refresh Token with Microsoft Graph claims it is expired even when being used

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am accessing Microsoft Graph on the behalf of other users who have authenticated with OAuth2.  Things were running fine, but after 90 days, I get the "AADSTS70008: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity."

But, it should not have been inactive.  Resource for the users are accessed  multiple times daily, and when the Access Token expires, the Refresh Token is used to get a new one.  Which works just as expected.

If using the Refresh Token to acquire a new Access Token is not "activity" for the Refresh Token, then what is?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#token-lifetimes), a Refresh Token will automatically expire if the user hasn't entered their credentials for 90 days:

> A single refresh token is valid for a maximum of 14 days. However, the refresh token might become invalid at any time for various reasons, so your app should continue to try to use a refresh token until it fails, or until your app replaces it with a new refresh token. **A refresh token also becomes invalid if it has been 90 days since the user has entered their credentials.**

UPDATE:

It was recently changed to `until-revoked`. You can read about the change [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/08/31/changes-to-the-token-lifetime-defaults-in-azure-ad/)

Comment: Just to add, the token lifetime for refresh tokens is currently being updated to be `until-revoked`. Expect this change soon.

Comment: Is there someplace I can monitor for when that change takes effect?

Comment: I just reviewed the documentation, and it seems like the ability to use until-revoked lies in the hands of the company who owns the AD.  So, as a provider of a service to customers, do each of them have to configure their AD for until-revoked?

Comment: The default was switched to until-revoked. This wouldn't apply if the tenant has customized the value to something else.

Comment: Any idea how that effects pending refresh tokens?  For example, if someone created the connection right before this change was made, will the until-revoked prevent them from expiring, or would that only take effect for new refresh tokens generated after this change had been put in place?

Comment: You'll need a new one. Although at this point I believe any existing tokens would have already expired.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old open question, so might not be helpful; though let me ask: when requesting a new access token, do you replace your ("used") refresh token with the new one coming along in the answer?

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token this is what I am doing within code of mine, which is maintaining a rolling access well over 90 days.

Hope this helps.